# android: host missing error in manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, moengage

I am trying to integrate `MoEngage SDK` for in app messaging and am following their docs.  I'm running into a `android:host missing` error in my manifest file.

I truly have no idea what it means or how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.  I've attached a picture.

[image]

Comment: It is better to post the contents of the file instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either get rid of that `<receiver>`, or make it work correctly. Use:

```
<data android:scheme="package" />
```

and filter out the broadcasts for other packages in Java code.

Or, on Android 4.4+, apparently this works:

```
<data android:scheme="package" android:android:sspPrefix="${applicationId}" />
```

(according to [Christopher Orr](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-ssp-data-intent-filter/); I haven't tried it personally)